Are $*$-Subalgebras Ever Dense in Their Double Commutant in Other Topologies?
We know $A$ a $*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$ is strongly dense in its double commutant $A''$. Are there particular conditions on $A$ or $H$ which allow us to strengthen this to one of the following:

$A$ is strongly-$^*$ dense in $A''$
$A$ is ultraweakly dense in $A''$
$A$ is ultrastrongly dense in $A''$
$A$ is Arens-Mackey dense in $A''$

(Since $A$ is always convex in this context, these are all stronger statements, with $4\implies 3\iff 2\implies 1$)

All of these are equivalent to strongly dense (also WOT-dense and ultrastrongly-$^\ast$ dense, if you want to complete the list) by a combination of Kaplansky density theorem and Hahn-Banach theorem.

@DavidGao I don't mean to trouble you, but could you elaborate on this proof? I was able to narrow it down to strong, strong-$*$, ultrastrong, and AM (all others reduce to one of these) but I cannot see how one would go further. Maybe this is the idea: It suffices to show AM is equivalent to strong. For each norm ball $B$, we know that on $A\cap B$ they are equivalent, since they are bounded-convex and we can make some Hahn-Banach argument over all such B?

strong is equivalent to strong-$^\ast$ because they have the same dual space, so Hahn-Banach implies the closures of a convex set coincide under these two topologies. The same goes for ultrastrong and AM. Kaplansky density implies that, for any $x$ in the unit ball of $A’’$, it is in the strong closure of the unit ball of $A$. But on the unit ball, strong and ultrastrong coincides, so $x$ is also in the ultrastrong closure of $A$, so $A’’$ is a subset of the ultrastrong closure of $A$. The converse is clear.

@DavidGao I see, thank you very much! Presumably then I can do the same procedure from my last post to prove that real $*$-subalgebras are AM dense in $B(H)_\mathbb{R}?$

I think so. You should go through the proof of Kaplansky density to check if working in the real case is a problem, but I don’t recall anything that can be problematic just going through the proof outline in my mind. Alternatively, ultrastrong can be identified with strong by just repeating $H$ infinitely many times, so at least that approach should work well.
